# Sybase (Adaptive Server Enterprise) Function to replace characters in a column

Tags: replace, sql-update, sap-ase

I want to replace characters in a column of sybase.

I want every character must be replace by 'x'
like 'A' to 'X'
'M' to 'X'

Suppose in a column there are 3 values-

1. 'Aman'- So 'Aman' must be replaced to 'xxxx'
2. 'ALEXANDER'- So 'ALEXANDER' must be replaced to 'xxxxxxxxx'
3. 'Robert' - so 'Robert' must be replaced to 'xxxxxx'.

For this in 'Oracle' there is one function `TRANSLATE`.

`Update Table_Name Set 
 Column_Name=TRANSLATE(Column_Name,'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz','xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx');`

This query will replace every character to 'x'. Does not matter, length of words vary or not. Donot depend on the length of column.

So please provide me the same functionality in 'SYBASE'.

Answer (score 0):

There are two approaches.

One would be creating a UDF and creating T-SQL code that would do the translation. But I must warn you, that this function would be very very slow.

The second approach would be to do something not quite what you have asked for, but very similar:

```
update tab set column_name = replicate('x', char_length(column_name))
```

This would also replace other characters like space, numbers, etc. But it would be a magnitude faster approach than the first one.

Comment: Thanks a lot Adam. It is doing the same as 'TRANSLATE' which is used in Oracle.
It's really helpful.

Comment: I also found one work around but it is very lengthy and also 26 times slower then your solution.
Syntex-
Update table_Name Set Column_Name=STR_Replace(UPPER(Convert(varchar(16384),column_Name)),'A','x');
This query will replace 'A' to 'x' and for remaining 25 characters we have to again create sql. So it is very lengthy but 'Something is better than nothing'.
Thanks for ur solution, I am implementing it :)

Comment: Also If we want to replace a specific character with another character in a column we can use it-
Syntex- Update table_Name Set Column_Name=STR_Replace(UPPER(Convert(varchar(16384),column_Name)),'A','x')